# webpack2: how to import Bootstrap CSS for react-bootstrap to find its styles?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, webpack, react-bootstrap, webpack-2

I am using webpack 2 and react-bootstrap in my project ; I can't find how to have bootstrap CSS styles properly applied it seems like the .css file is not loaded, no matter which `import` statement I tried to use.

As far as I understand I do not need the full bootstrap package with javascript etc. since I am using react-bootstrap ; I just need the CSS. So I added this in my `main.js` file:

```
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
```

It seems to work (no error message) but the styles are not applied...

I configured the css loader in my webpack config file as described on webpack 2 documentation.

Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: Did you set the option `modules: true` in your `css-loader`? That would make css locally scoped. It would be good if you posted your webpack config, there are many different configurations in the docs.

Comment: @MichaelJungo thanks a lot!!! That was it :) I copied config from webpack2 web page and there was `modules: true` indeed... Would be good to know if I can decide if I want CSS rules scoped in a module or not rather than having a global option?

Comment: @MichaelJungo I would be happy to upvote your answer if you send one :)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

When setting `modules: true` in the `css-loader`, the CSS is locally scoped by default, but you need them to be available globally. The simplest solution is to remove `modules: true` entirely. You could still use modules in your own CSS files by using [:local](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/css-loader/#css-scope).

But if you would like to use modules, there are some workarounds to import globals.

## Defining separate rules

Instead of enabling modules for all the CSS files, you can make two different rules, that match the desired files. So let's say all CSS imports from `node_modules` should be treated as regular (global) CSS. The rules would look like this:

```
{
  // For all .css files except from node_modules
  test: /\.css$/,
  exclude: /node_modules/,
  use: [
    'style-loader',
    { loader: 'css-loader', options: { modules: true } }
  ]
},
{
  // For all .css files in node_modules
  test: /\.css$/,
  include: /node_modules/,
  use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader']
}
```

Of course you can be more specific in what you want to include/exclude, if you don't want the entire `node_modules`.

## Specifying loaders inline

You can specify the loaders in the `import` and webpack will use those over the configured ones. You would import bootstrap as follows:

```
import '!style-loader!css-loader!bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
```

This is just a quick workaround without having to change any config, but it's probably not desirable, especially when having multiple such cases.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed explanation