# How to exclude bootstrap files when CSS modules is enabled

Tags: webpack, bootstrap-4, css-loader

I am using both bootstrap and CSS modules by enabling the `css-loader`'s modules option in my project and unfortunately `css-loader` applys scoping on the bootstrap files too.

I have an `app.scss` where I am importing all bootstrap sass files. And I import the `app.scss` file into my `app.js` file:

`import "./app.scss";`

```
  { test: /\.scss$/,
    use: [
        {loader: "style-loader"},
        {
          loader: "css-loader",
          options: {
            sourceMap: true,
            modules: true,
            localIdentName: "[path][name]__[local]--[hash:base64:5]"
          }
        },
        {loader: "sass-loader"}
      ]
```

for example bootstrap's `.table` class turns to something like `.app__table--19A_z`

How do you think I can disable CSS modules for bootstrap files.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [webpack2: how to import Bootstrap CSS for react-bootstrap to find its styles?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42436728/webpack2-how-to-import-bootstrap-css-for-react-bootstrap-to-find-its-styles)

Comment: Defining separate rules looks like a reasonable solution but it still pollute the bootstrap files even if I set exclude: `/node_modules/`

Comment: are your problem solved?

Answer (score 1):

It could be accomplish with [**module rule.exclude**](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/module/#condition)

> The Condition must NOT match. The convention is to provide a string or array of strings here, but it's not enforced.

so to exclude the boostrap scss file should like this:

```
{
  test: /\.scss$/,
  use: ...
  exclude: [
    path.resolve(__dirname, "node_modules/bootstrap"),
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This cannot be accomplished simply with `exclude` because you are importing the bootstrap scss files into your app's scss files with a single entry point.

Nor can it be fully accomplished with the :global selector scope, but this can definitely come close to doing the job, especially if you are not using postcss.

To see an ongoing discussion on this topic view this github issue: https://github.com/css-modules/css-modules/pull/65

Answer (score 0):

Yes Drew2 advice to look to githup issue is very helpful.
Add a query to bootstrap css import path:

```
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css?bootstrap'
import 'bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap'
import App from './App'
```

And in webpack.config use "oneOf" for css rule:

```
    rules: [
  ...
  {
    test: /\.(css|pcss)$/,
    oneOf: [
      {
        resourceQuery: /bootstarp/,
        use: [
          'style-loader',
          {
            loader: 'css-loader',
            options: {
              sourceMap: true,
              importLoaders: 1,
            },
          },
          {
            loader: 'postcss-loader',
            options: { sourceMap: true },
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        use: [
          'style-loader',
          {
            loader: 'css-loader',
            options: {
              sourceMap: true,
              importLoaders: 1,
              modules: {
                localIdentName: mode === 'development' ? '[folder]_[name]_[local]_[hash:base64:5]' : '[hash:base64:8]',
              },
            },
          },
          {
            loader: 'postcss-loader',
            options: { sourceMap: true },
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },

  ...
],
```

OR with include/exclude:

```
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css'
import 'bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap'
import App from './App'


      rules: [
...
{
    test: /\.(css|pcss)$/,
    exclude: /bootstrap\/dist\/css\/bootstrap\.css$/,
    use: [
      'style-loader',
      {
        loader: 'css-loader',
        options: {
          sourceMap: true,
          importLoaders: 1,
          modules: {
            localIdentName: mode === 'development' ? '[folder]_[name]_[local]_[hash:base64:5]' : '[hash:base64:8]',
          },
          // exportOnlyLocals: false,
        },
      },
      {
        loader: 'postcss-loader',
        options: { sourceMap: true },
      },
    ],
  },

  {
    test: /\.(css|pcss)$/,
    include: /bootstrap\/dist\/css\/bootstrap\.css$/,
    use: [
      'style-loader',
      {
        loader: 'css-loader',
        options: {
          sourceMap: true,
          importLoaders: 1,
          // exportOnlyLocals: false,
        },
      },
      {
        loader: 'postcss-loader',
        options: { sourceMap: true },
      },
    ],
  },
```

...
]