# How to apply Bootstrap CSS in a create-react-app application with CSS modules

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, reactjs, webpack, react-bootstrap, create-react-app

I would like to use `Bootstrap` in my `create-react-app` application. I would like all of my `CSS` to be scoped to their respective components (via `CSS modules`) but I would like to apply the `Bootstrap CSS` to my entire application so that the standard controls look a bit nicer.
First, I've installed `Bootstrap` via

```
npm install --save bootstrap
```

After I did some research on stackoverflow I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42436728/webpack2-how-to-import-bootstrap-css-for-react-bootstrap-to-find-its-styles) and tried to modify my `webpack.config.dev.js` file. It now looks like this:

```
 {
        test: /\.css$/,
        exclude: '/node_modules/bootstrap/',
        use: [
          require.resolve('style-loader'),
          {
            loader: require.resolve('css-loader'),
            options: {
              importLoaders: 1,
              modules: true,
              localIdentName: '[name]__[local]__[hash:base64:5]',
            },
          },
          {
            loader: require.resolve('postcss-loader'),
            options: {
              // Necessary for external CSS imports to work
              // https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/issues/2677
              ident: 'postcss',
              plugins: () => [
                require('postcss-flexbugs-fixes'),
                autoprefixer({
                  browsers: [
                    '>1%',
                    'last 4 versions',
                    'Firefox ESR',
                    'not ie < 9', // React doesn't support IE8 anyway
                  ],
                  flexbox: 'no-2009',
                }),
              ],
            },
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        // don't apply CSS modules to all .css files in node_modules/bootstrap
        test: /\.css$/,
        include: '/node_modules/bootstrap/',
        use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader']
      },
```

I am importing the `Bootstrap CSS` in my `index.js` like so:

```
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap-theme.css';

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
registerServiceWorker();
```

However, the `Bootstrap CSS` does not get applied. Can anyone point my into the right direction why that is? Do I need a different config my `webpack.config.dev.js` file?

Comment: Are you getting any error in terminal?

Comment: no, simply nothing happens and the CSS Bootstrap styles are not applied globally

Comment: I'm not sure if it helps but, you can check my medium article: https://medium.com/monitisemea/how-to-import-bootstrap-using-webpack-7245eba98056

Comment: Unfortunately that did not help